# How to use custom JS to change source of line plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

My dataframe has several columns. I want to use a dropdown to trigger a change in the y-values.

So far I have

```py
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, save
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Dropdown, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 2, 2], "c": [3, 2, 1]})
    source = ColumnDataSource(df)

    fig = figure()
    line = fig.line(x="a", y="b", source=source)

    dropdown = Dropdown(label="Choose y", menu=[("b", "b"), ("c", "c")])
    code = """
    // how to set the line source equal to "this.item"?
    """
    update_line_callback = CustomJS(args={"dropdown": dropdown, "line": line, "source": source}, code=code)
    dropdown.js_on_event("menu_item_click", update_line_callback)

    output_file("out.html")
    save(column(children=[fig, dropdown]))
```

How do I link the dropdown item with the line source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One working option is to create a column in your data source you want to show and change this values if the `Dropdown` is called by the selected name. The new name is `this.item` if you call `dropdown.js_on_event("menu_item_click", *callback)`

Here is the working code:

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, save
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Dropdown, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

# create some source
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 2, 2], "c": [3, 2, 1]})
df["show"] = df["b"]
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# figure
fig = figure()
line = fig.line(x="a", y="show", source=source)
dropdown = Dropdown(label="Choose y", menu=[("b", "b"), ("c", "c")])

# overwrite show values with new selection
code = """
    let s = source.data
    s["show"] = s[this.item]
    source.change.emit();
"""
dropdown.js_on_event("menu_item_click", CustomJS(args={"source": source}, code=code))

# output figure
show(column(children=[fig, dropdown]))
```

Comment: I see, so the approach is not to change the y value of the `fig.line` but instead change the data underneath.