# Fix right-side of plot in place when zooming in/out

Tags: python, bokeh

When I zoom out the following Bokeh plot:

[image]

A bunch of whitespace is added to both sides of the data:

[image]

How can I make it so that the right-hand side of the plot is fixed, so that zooming out will only create whitespace on the left-hand side? For example, this is my desired zoom-out look:

[image]

This is the code that initializes the plot:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.driving import linear
from bokeh.models.tools import PanTool, WheelZoomTool
p = figure(sizing_mode="stretch_both", y_axis_location="right", x_axis_type="datetime")
pan_tool = p.select(dict(type=PanTool))
pan_tool.dimensions="width"
zoom_tool = p.select(dict(type=WheelZoomTool))
zoom_tool.dimensions="width"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `CustomJS` callback. Define a `ColumnDataSource` as source and look for the maximum x value on thof the source. If you have multiple renderers or multiple sources, you have to find the mximum of the maximums.

**Minimal Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Line, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=500, height=300)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=data, y=data))
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)
callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(p=p, source=source),
    code="""
        p.x_range.end = Math.max(...source.data['x'])
        p.change.emit();
    """
)

p.x_range.js_on_change("end", callback)
show(p)
```

Comment: Does this approach work even if the data is being dynamically & gradually added to the plot in real-time? Or does using `ColumnDataSource` imply a fixed input dataset?

Comment: I know that it is possible to change the change the values inside the CDS, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180583/how-to-use-custom-js-to-change-source-of-line-plot/71204066#71204066). I don't see any reason why the CDS can't be extended. Give it a try.